# CSS in ajax-loaded content is not applied

Tags: css, ajax, fancybox

Sorry if this is obvious but I just don't know what more to do.

I am using [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/api) jQuery plugin to load html content into a modal, but the content doesn't show the css styles of the main document.

CSS rules are called in the main document AND inside the loaded html in a `<style>` tag, but nothing.

How can I fix this without having to apply individually each element's css with jQuery `.css()` calls?

Thank you

Note: I know this may be [over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445956/ajax-loaded-content-doesnt-inherit-css)-[duplicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308924/firefox-wont-render-css-styles-on-content-loaded-with-jquery-ajax), but I still haven't found the right solution.

Edit: Ajax-loaded content is inside an `iframe`

Comment: Is the modal a div? Are you loading in HTML content that includes extra `<html>` or `<body>` tags, or anything else that creates a region that's syntactically ambiguous? Are you unwittingly using child selectors like `div#foo > div`, where instead you'd need descendant selectors like `div#foo div` to target the dynamically loaded content that may now be deeper in the document?

Comment: Any chance we can see some more code?

Comment: the content is inside an `iframe` inside a `div` the way Fancybox does it. Since posting the question, I've fixed the problem with the _inline_ style not rendering -it now renders ok. I was referencing the content with `id`s from outside the `iframe` which doesn't seem to work. But I am still interested in finding a more elegant solution (make the iframe content render as the main css mandates).
The page in question is http://wikaina.com/clients/irismorata.com/prensa/

Comment: If it's an iframe, it's an independent html document with its own styles. It will not be affected by styles in the "outer" document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, as you mention in the comments, you're actually loading content into an iframe, this loaded content will not be affected by styles in the container document. They're two distinct HTML pages, despite the illusion created by the iframe.

Your best bet is to configure the content you're loading to use the same set of styles and style sheets as the container document, or a subset thereof. Treat it like just another HTML page on your site.

Comment: any suggestion as of how to attach the _outer_ css to the iframe html via jQuery? Thanks

Comment: @NaoiseGolden, you could try something along these lines: `$('#iframe').contents().find('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet"...>')`

Comment: It didn't work so I am going with the inline code. Thanks for the snippet anyway.